# How to use the class data of a json element that have colon in name - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gson

I have the following Json:

```
_embedded: {
  wp:featuredmedia: [
    {
      id: 9060,
      date: "2018-05-28T17:41:21",
      author: 2,
      caption: {
        rendered: ""
      },
      source_url: "h.t.t.p.s://mydomain_com/myimage.jpg",
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using httpOk and Gson to deserialize, I have the following data classes.

```
data class Embedded(
    val wp:featuredmedia: List<Wpfeaturedmedia>
)

data class Wpfeaturedmedia(
    val source_url: String
)
```

Everything works correctly, but my problem is when it comes to obtaining the image of `source_url`, because the name `wp:featuredmedia` has two points (colon). 
**How do I make the class work correctly?**
[image: Image with the error]

**UPDATE: WORK NOW WITH**

```
data class Embedded(
        @SerializedName("wp:featuredmedia") val wpfeaturedmedia: List<Wpfeaturedmedia>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple - name your field `wpfeaturedmedia` (without the colon) and it will be mapped correctly.

Edit:
It seems I was wrong - Gson simply skips `wp:featuredmedia` during deserialization unless field `wpfeaturedmedia` is annotated with `@SerializedName("wp:featuredmedia")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply
If I use the name of the variable without the colon, when I want to get the value of `source_url` it does not recognize me. Sample: `val thumbnailImageView = homeOfertas[position]._embedded.wpfeaturedmedia.source_url`

Comment: `wpfeaturemedia` is a list, so your code should be: `val thumbnailImageView = homeOfertas[position]._embedded.wpfeaturedmedia[0].source_url`

Comment: Thanks friend, now he works with me `@SerializedName("wp:featuredmedia") val wpfeaturedmedia: List<Wpfeaturedmedia>`

Answer (score 1):

you may use @JsonProperty

```
data class ResponseData(
   @JsonProperty("wp:featuredmedia")
   val wpfeaturedmedia: List<SubData>
) { data class SubData(...)}
```